# Trouble with seasonal argument of arima function in R

Tags: r, forecasting

Here's my code:

```
arimafit <- arima(x1, order = c(5,1,5), seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,0)))

fcast1 <- forecast(arimafit,50)

summary(fcast1)
```

and the result is:

```
Forecast method: ARIMA(5,1,5)                   

Model Information:

Series: x1 

ARIMA(5,1,5)
```

That is, it doesn't seam to be using the seasonal argument. I've done plenty of googling and playing around with the argument to no avail. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. A [reporoducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) makes it possible for help to be forthcoming. In your case, can you upload `dput(x1)` (or a reasonable subset), and the packages your are using.

Answer (score 3):

The seasonal argument also needs the period to be specified if the frequency of `x1` is not already set. Read the help function for `arima()`.